# TCPClient Threading

Tags: c#, thread-safety, tcpclient

I'm developing a game server. Through TCPListener I accept clients.

```
var Listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, CommonConfig.Settings.GamePort);
Listener.Start();
ListenerStarted = true;
while (ListenerStarted)
{
    TcpClient tcpClient = await Listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
    ProcessClientTearOff(tcpClient);
}
```

Then through ReadAsync is getting the data from the client.

```
byte[] Buffer = new byte[8192];
int i = await Stream.ReadAsync(Buffer, 0, 8192);
```

After that, the data is processed using the method

```
RequestHandling(byte[] data)
```

and performing various actions. Clients actively interact between each other and therefore there are problems with thread safety. I was looking for information on how to properly organize the server structure and found a possible case that the data is being received asynchronously (as I have now), but the processing and execution of actions occurs in one thread.

One thread to accept clients and get data, one thread to process and execute, one thread to send data to clients.
But I can not understand how this can be realized. Through Task, you can specify the order in which the methods are executed, but only before running tasks. Is it possible to run all the processing of packets in a separate thread so that all actions are executed synchronously in the order of the queue? Or is there any alternative to this?

Answer (score 0):

The question is fairly vague which is understandable given that you are seeking a general concept to organize this.

You don't need a separate thread to process a queue. Usually, a lock is an easier solution. A lock has an internal queue as am implementation detail. The queue contains the threads that are waiting to enter.

A good pattern for your case seems to be the following. Make each connection thread/task execute this loop:

```
while (true) {
 var message = await ReceiveMessageFromNetwork();
 lock (globalLock) {
  ApplyMessage(message); //no IO here
 }
}
```

The queue is implicit in the lock. I marked some code as "no IO" because you have to quickly leave the lock so that other threads/tasks can enter.